# How to be the first site in google search?

Tags: search, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I searched the title of my website in google search, and although it is a very specific tile, I didn't find my site.
My question is that how can be the first sites in google search?

I heard that google doesn't look up `<meta>`s anymore and using another method.Is it true?

Comment: See [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization#Methods)

Comment: Did it occur to you that if anybody knew how to do this, this knowledge would be worth millions of dollars?

Comment: You should contact the owner of the site that does come up first. I am sure they would be happy to tell you their secret to success!

Comment: Is your site indexed at all? Or maybe banned?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Google doesn't look at all the meta tags, it look's at description but not keywords. But any way put meta tags (for other search engines and to make sure), but content helps Google (a good content is very good for Google), so put a bit of text, not image text and linking to other pages doesn't help.

But you will have to wait until Google's crawler scans your site. Could take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general. Basically you are asking for how to rank high on google search with a specific keyword. You can do SEO to try to "game" the ranking system. But ultimately, your content of your site determinate how well it will be ranked by google. Google does it by judging how many back links to your site and how relevant your content is based on the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways to answer this question. Here's the low-hanging fruit: http://www.google.com/submityourcontent/index.html

The search game between SEO professionals and search engines has evolved enough that anything too overtly gameable is out by now, so meta keywords are long gone.